# SQL Server PIVOT multiple dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

Hi I have my data in a table like this:

```
Herd | Tag | Byr | Mob | Date        | Trait | Value
-----|-----|-----|-----|-------------|-------|-------
6002 | 1/08| 2008| 1   | 2015-08-17  | LWT   | 425
6002 | 1/08| 2008| 3   | 2015-12-22  | LWT   | 516
6002 | 1/08| 2008| 4   | 2016-04-06  | LWT   | 688
```

I need it changed from Long to wide format using the PIVOT function

```
Herd | Tag | Byr | Mob | 2015-08-17 | Mob | 2015-12-22 | Mob | 2016-04-06
-----|-----|-----|-----|------------|-----|------------|-----|------------
6002 | 1/08| 2008| 1   | 425        |  3  |  516       |  4  |    688
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I also have multiple Dates (hundreds.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Dynamic Pivot for multiple columns

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) 
Set @SQL = Stuff((Select  Distinct ',' +QuoteName(concat('Mob_',Date))+' as Mob,'+QuoteName(Date)
                   From   Yourtable 
                   Order by 1 
                   For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 

Select  @SQL = '
Select [Herd],[Tag],[Byr],' + @SQL + '
From (
        Select [Herd],[Tag],[Byr]
              ,B.* 
        From  YourTable A
        Cross Apply (
                     Values (concat(''Mob_'',A.Date),cast(A.Mob as nvarchar(50)))
                           ,(concat('''',A.Date)    ,cast(A.Value as nvarchar(50)))
                    ) B (Item,Value)
     ) A
Pivot (max([Value]) For [Item] in (' + Replace(@SQL,' as Mob','') + ') ) p'

Exec(@SQL);
```

**Returns**

[image]

> **EDIT**

Updated for 2014  ... Concat() and Values

> **EDIT 2:**

Another option to casting a nvarchar(50), you could use format().  For example:

```
             Values (concat(''Mob_'',A.Date),Format(A.Mob,''0''))
                   ,(concat('''',A.Date)    ,Format(cast(A.Value as decimal(18,2)),''#,##0.00''))
            ) B (Item,Value)
```

Comment: So my table is called "Trait" so I need to replace YourTable with trait?

Comment: @proctor Just to be clear, are you using the code listed above?  ie not a previous version

Comment: Yes Ive copied your code - I'm running SQL Server 2014

Comment: @proctor you tagged 2008.   I would have used concat() and values rather than Union All.   Do you want the change?

Comment: Yeah sorry John - if you could please

Comment: Thanks. "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '125.5' to data type smallint." do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @proctor what are the data types for Mob and Value?

Comment: Mob is smallint and Value is nvarchar(50)

Comment: @proctor See in the cross Apply, we now cast both Mob and Value as nvarchar(50)

Comment: thanks. I'm a little confused, one place you have "Yourtable" then another place you have "Yourtable A"? should they both be called Trait?

Comment: @proctor just replace the word "YourTable" with Trait.  Leave the "A" where it is

Comment: @proctor the A is just a Alias.  Easier to refer to an item.  I would rather type A.Value than SomeTableName.Value

Comment: @proctor See Edit 2:  the format() option.  this way Mob will look like an Int and Value can be formatted with commas and two decimals

Comment: So I also leave the ",B.*"  as a B?

Comment: @proctor yes.  Only change the YourTable

Comment: Thanks John! Especially for your patience